# How to use Spring Cloud Stream to produce & consume Avro messages using Confluent Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, registry, schema, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform

I can run example by following [Start Streaming with Kafka and Spring Cloud](http://www.beeworks.be/blog/2016/start-streaming-kafka-spring-cloud.html), but unfortunately it doesn't use confluent schema registry. I read the confluent schema registry part of [Spring Cloud Stream reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_using_confluent_s_schema_registry), but it didn't work with my confluent 3.0.0 and the guide doesn't mention how to produce Avro message using confluent schema registry. So, can anyone guide me how to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Cloud Stream is not yet compatible with Confluent Schema Registry. See discussion in this thread https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/850